# Obtener la información dentro de un archivo Microsoft Access mediante PHP

Tags: php, laravel, ms-access-2010

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación web la cual requiere del uso de un reloj checador, al principio tenía la idea de usar el `API` que este provee, pero por problemas de compatibilidad con el sistema; esto no es posible. Básicamente el checador arroja un archivo en `Microsoft Access` que contiene registros que deseo utilizar. **¿Hay alguna forma de poder procesar esa información mediante el uso de PHP?**

La idea es que se evite el registro manual de toda esa información y posteriormente hacer los cálculos que yo requiera hacer. Mi idea principal es simplemente leer el archivo, tomar los registros y pasarlos a una base de datos `SQL`.

---

**Nota**: Cabe destacar que estoy usando **Laravel 5.2**, si hay algún paquete que trate este tipo de cosas, sería excelente.

Saludos.

Comment: has intentado algo? si buscas en Google verás que hay se puede. Hay un driver `odbc` para conectar a bases de datos Access.

Comment: Busco una solución más actualizada y por su puesto que si he buscado en Google, sería poco pertinente preguntar antes de buscar ¿No crees?

Comment: Si, lo creo. Quizá hayas buscado antes pero en tu pregunta no aparece nada que hayas intentado o buscado. No se a que te refieres con "más actualizado" pero no creo que haya nada más actual que `PDO + odbc`. Mira este ejemplo: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19808531/1675789

Answer (score 0):

Hola recuerda que disponemos de las funciones de conexión ODBC con bases de datos en php, no hay funcion especificamente para bases access pero puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

conectar Access con PHP.

Si tenemos nuestra página alojada en un proveedor de hosting y queremos conectar Access con PHP, si es que lo permiten (pues lo típico en esos casos es utilizar una base de datos MySQL), tendríamos que preguntarles cómo crear el DSN en sus sistemas.

Una vez tengamos el DSN utilizaremos un código de conexión como este:

```
$conn_access = odbc_connect ("guiarte_access", "", "");
```

Con la función odbc_connect() se conecta con una base de datos por ODBC, indicando el nombre del DSN en el primer parámetro y luego el usuario y la contraseña. En Access normal es que no se tenga siquiera usuario y contraseña, por lo que esos dos parámetros los he pasado con una cadena vacía. Nos devuelve el identificador de la conexión con la base de datos.

Para ejecutar una sentencia SQL utilizaremos la función odbc_exec(). De este modo:

```
$rs_access = odbc_exec ($conn_access, "select * from tabla");
```

Como se puede ver, odbc_exec() recibe el identificador de la conexión obtenido anteriormente y la sentencia SQL a ejecutar. Devuelve un identificador del conjunto de registros resultado de ejecutar la sentencia.

Luego utilizaremos funciones como odbc_fetch_array() o odbc_fetch_object() para acceder a cada uno de los registros obtenidos en el conjunto de resultados.

Un código completo de conexión con una base de datos Access podría ser el siguiente:

```
if ($conn_access = odbc_connect ( "guiarte_access", "", "")){
echo "Conectado correctamente";
$ssql = "select * from libros";
if($rs_access = odbc_exec ($conn_access, $ssql)){
   echo "La sentencia se ejecutó correctamente";
   while ($fila = odbc_fetch_object($rs_access)){
      echo "<br>" . $fila->titulo;
   }
}else{
   echo "Error al ejecutar la sentencia SQL";
}
```

} else{
    echo "Error en la conexión con la base de datos";
}

Nota: Las funciones odbc_fetch_array() y odbc_fetch_object(), así como otras funciones de PHP para el acceso por ODBC a bases de datos, son idénticas o muy similares en su utilización a las funciones propias para otras bases de datos como MySQL. Cambiar los nombres de las funciones como mysql_fetch_array() por sus correspondientes, como odbc_fetch_array().

avisa si te funciona, un saludo